# MySQL - Join last row of related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that I have searched for and can't find answers that offer any help.

There are 3 tables: `orders`, `customers`, and `teams`.  Each order has a customer and a team.  My problem is that for each customer, I am trying to get their total orders, and then **the team that was assigned to their last order.**

My query so far (works fine):

```
SELECT c.id, MAX(o.timestamp) AS "Last Order", COUNT(o.id) AS "Total Orders", SUM(o.price) AS "Total Spend"
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN customers c ON o.customer = c.id
WHERE o.timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

I can't figure out how to join the `team.name` for the last order they placed, without affecting the rest of the query that I have.

**Sample Tables and Desired Result:**

Customers:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Teams:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ Red         ║
║  2 ║ Blue        ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Orders:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════╦══════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║  ID   ║       TIMESTAMP     ║ CUSTOMER ║ TEAM ║ VALUE ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 34656 ║ 2012-03-04 14:23:44 ║        1 ║    2 ║    20 ║
║ 37345 ║ 2012-04-12 11:32:07 ║        2 ║    2 ║    25 ║
║ 38220 ║ 2012-07-18 09:53:54 ║        1 ║    2 ║    15 ║
║ 39496 ║ 2012-07-03 10:11:32 ║        1 ║    1 ║    38 ║
║ 41752 ║ 2012-09-17 19:34:05 ║        1 ║    2 ║     9 ║
║ 43734 ║ 2012-11-23 07:52:12 ║        2 ║    1 ║    20 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════╩══════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

How do I select a result like:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║      LAST_ORDER     ║ TEAM_NAME ║ TOTAL_ORDERS ║ TOTAL_SPEND ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║ 2012-09-17 19:34:05 ║ Blue      ║           4  ║          82 ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║ 2012-11-23 07:52:12 ║ Red       ║           2  ║          45 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result just like what you did on your previous question? `:)`

Comment: how many fields do you need from team table? if that's just one field, then simple correlated query will do.

Comment: @JW. Sure can!  @Bulat I just need the `name` of the team assigned to the customer's last order

Comment: Why not a trigger? take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661314/best-and-optimal-way-to-join-max-value-from-other-table/26664982#26664982

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query similar to this:

```
select c.id,
  c.name,
  o1.Last_Order,
  t.name Team_Name,
  o3.Total_Orders,
  o3.Total_Spend
from customers c
inner join
(
  select max(timestamp) Last_Order,
    max(id) Last_id,
    customer
  from orders
  WHERE timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
  group by customer
) o1
  on c.id = o1.customer
inner join orders o2
  on c.id = o2.customer
  and o1.Last_Order = o2.timestamp
  and o1.Last_id = o2.id
inner join teams t
  on o2.team = t.id
inner join
(
  select count(team) Total_Orders,
    sum(value) Total_Spend,
    customer
  from orders 
  WHERE timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
  group by customer
) o3
  on c.id = o3.customer
WHERE o2.timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8258a/13)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, but as with JW's I'm still getting about 40% less rows returned with this query, when comparing with the query in my original post.

Comment: @BadHorsie Can you expand your data sample, even edit the sql fiddle with more data?

Answer (score 1):

I like to do this using a `group_concat` trick:

```
SELECT c.id, MAX(o.timestamp) AS "Last, Order", COUNT(o.id) AS "Total Orders",
       SUM(o.price) AS "Total Spend",
       substring_index(group_concat(teamname order by o.timestamp desc), ',', 1) as LastTeam
FROM orders o left outer join
     customers c ON o.customer = c.id left outer join
     teams t
     on o.teamid = t.id
WHERE o.timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  You have a typo at `substring_index` by the way, and missing comma after "Total Spend" (I can't edit it; too short).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be giving me the team from their last order.  Perhaps one of their other orders, but not the last one that conforms to the conditions of the query.

Comment: May this solution syntax is not correct BUT the concept is the best cause avoiding SUB-SELECT! thx!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        a.Name Customer_Name,
        c.TimeStamp Last_ORDER,
        c.Name AS Team_Name,
        COUNT(b.Customer) AS Total_Order,
        SUM(b.Value) AS Total_Spend
FROM    Customers a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.ID = b.Customer
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  o.Customer, 
                    o.TimeStamp,
                    q.Name
            FROM    Orders o
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  Customer, MAX(ID) max_ID
                        FROM    Orders
                        GROUP   BY Customer
                    ) p ON o.Customer = p.Customer AND
                            o.ID = p.max_ID
                    INNER JOIN Team q
                        ON o.Team = q.ID
        ) c ON a.ID = c.Customer
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e87b/4)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with date condition*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e87b/8)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*between dates*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e87b/9)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now.  I need to add some conditions to the main query though, to ensure that I only select customers who ordered since 1st Jan 2012.  I tried adding a `WHERE b.timestamp > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'` before the last `GROUP BY` but it doesn't seem to be working, as I am getting about half the number of total rows that I was before.

Comment: ok, you need to add the condition on the inner most query, [SQLFiddle Demo (click here)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e87b/8) and here's the query for getting between dates,eg. `TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-30 00:00:00'` [SQLFiddle Demo (click here)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e87b/9)

Comment: I am still getting about 40% less rows than I was with my original query without the inner joins.  Is it likely the joins are preventing some rows from being returned?  The original query results should be unchanged other than the addition of the extra column for the team name.

Comment: based on your records aove, what would be the result if I want to get the orders between dates, `BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-30 00:00:00'`